# Class diagram drawn from Use case description

Tags: uml

I know that I can build a Class diagram from a database E-R Diagram (tables become classes, tables properties are the classes properties...)

But I'm looking for informations (or step by step like) to create a class diagram from a use case description (or even a sequence diagram).

(All I found now is that the sequence diagram objects becomes classes and the stimuli messages methodes)

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing this backwards. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @JimL.  This is what I told in class. Teacher said there are 2 way to build class diagram ... 1st from the E-R and 2nd from the the use case description.... so From the E-R it s pretty straightforward but from the use case description I'm having issues. The problem is I cant find my teacher for explanations

Comment: Look at the ICONIX process. This once helped me. Describing it here is by far too much.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Okay. I'll do that. Thx

Comment: I'm pretty sure your teacher meant the textual use case description rather then the sequence diagram. From that text you can deduce the classes, attributes and operations. Reverse engineering a class diagram based on a sequence diagram seems a bit silly.

Comment: @GeertBellekens OMG then I'm completly off course here. Is there any exemple (or book) on the internet I could read to see that process so that I can better understand it. I've googled but no good results.

Comment: This may help you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49749/uml-going-from-use-case-to-class-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to TA in software engineering, and both create a class diagram from a textual definition as well as create a class diagram from a sequence diagram were regular exam questions.

Creating class diagrams from a specification should be covered in your lectures since its one of the most important things to learn. [This site explains the workflow quite well in my opinion.](https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/constructing-class-diagrams)

It is important to note, that in software engineering there never is just one solution. You can tackle problems in multiple ways each with their own benefits and problems. The most important step to learning is doing it yourself, just looking at solutions won't help you.

For creating class diagrams from a sequence diagram: 
Objects are instance of classes, in most sequence diagrams there is only one instance of any given class. Therefore "objects become classes" is not technically correct but the right intention.
Messages represent method calls on the receiving object, ergo you need to add these methods to the class of the receiving object.

Any communicating classes need to be associated, else they could not call their methods.

We put focus on only modelling the information you can derive from the sequence diagram, e.g. in most cases you do not know multiplicities of associations.

Comment: I don't know about exam questions, but I've never encountered a situation in real life where you would need to construct a class diagram based on a sequence diagram. If you were able to construct the sequence diagram then the classes and methods must already exist. If this is really an exam question then I think it is a silly one.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I upvoted your comment. One thing to note: I have used sequence diagrams to add missing operations, which is kind of working backwards. MagicDraw and maybe other tools allow you to add missing operations and signal receptions from a sequence diagram.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Sure, but OP is in university/school and his teacher mentioned creating class diagrams from sequence diagrams, therefore i offered my knowledge on that topic.

Comment: @JimL. Yes, in EA you can also directly from the SD add operations to the lifelines classifier. But I would consider that more of a "modelling in parallel" situation then actually reverse engineering the data model from the SD.

Comment: @Eashi It's not really clear if the professor meant the sequence diagram or the textual description of the use case. It would make a lot more sense if to start from the textual description.

Comment: @Eashi Thanks. I did as you said. It was the only was to get something coherent I guess. Plus on another question here they told me the receiving objet is the one implementing the method. Thanks for the advice.